# Analysis questions

Tags: real-analysis

Sorry I'm not exactly sure how to format these. I've come across a few questions that have had me stumped. I will type the questions and then explain my work. Any help would be appreciated.

1. Let $X = C_b((0,1))$ and $S = \{ f \in X \mid f \text{ has compact support in $(0,1)$ and } \| f \|_\infty \le 1\}$. Then (a) show that $S$ is not closed in $X$, (b) describe the closure $\overline{X}$ of $S$ in $X$, and (c) show $\overline{S}$ is compact.
2. Fix $f \in C_b(\mathbb{R})$. Let $S = \{ f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, where $f_n(x) = f(x-n)$. Must $S$ be equicontinuous?

For problem 1, I'm using the definition of support$(f)$ that is the closure of the subset of $X$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$. I need $f_n \in S$ with $f_n \to f$ uniformly and $f \notin S$. I think the condition that must fail is the compact support being in $(0,1)$, since if $\| f_n\| \to f$ and $\|f_n\| \le 1$ then $\|f\| \le 1$, correct? One function suggested to me was taking
$$ f_n(x) = \max\left\{ 0, 1 - |2x-1| - \frac{1}{n} \right\} $$

I believe I can show that $f_n \to 1-|2x-1|$ under the sup norm, but $f_n \in S$ and $f \notin S$. Is there an easier example (I wouldn't have thought of this one)

But I'm not sure how to proceed with (b). Is it just the set of $f \in X$ with $\|f \|_\infty \le 1$ and supp($f) = \overline{(0,1)} = [0,1]$? And for $c$, I need to show $\overline{S}$ is compact, or equivalently, totally bounded and complete. Not much progress here.

Now for problem 2, I think I could pick $f$ with compact support, then $f$ is still in $C_b(\mathbb{R})$, but $f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to zero. But I still can't say anything about equicontinuity. Is there a relationship between the two, maybe through Arzela Ascoli?

I apologize for the wall of text. As you can probably tell, I'm relatively new to these things. Thanks again for any help.

Comment: 1(b) just say closure of $S$ in $X$ 1(c)  If you've shown $S$ is not closed, then $S$ is not compact. 2. There are functions in $X,$ like $\sin(x^2),$ that are not uniformly continuous.

Comment: Thanks. For 1(c) i am considering if $\overline{S}$ is compact, though.

Comment: I think I got problem 2. Since $f$ is continuous, for all $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that $$|x-y| = |(x-n) - (y-n)| < \delta \implies |f(x-n)-f(y-n)|<\epsilon.$$ So I can pick that corresponding $\delta$ and hence $f_n(x) = f(x-n)$ is equicontinuous. Was there any relationship to this in the problem that you see? The example pops up here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity#Equicontinuity_and_uniform_convergence)

Answer (score 0):

Hint for 1(a): For each $n$ there is a function $g_n \in S$ such that $g_n=1$ on $[1/n,1-1/n],$ and $0\le g_n\le 1$ on $[0,1].$ Let $f(x) = \sin (\pi x).$ Then $f \notin S,$ but each $g_nf\in S$ and $g_nf \to f$ in $X.$